# mysql group by and filtering the values in each grouped record

Tags: mysql

i have a table of users im grouping by age, but each user also has a nationality and if one of the users nationality is US i want that to be value in the group record, currently it seems to take the first nationality it finds, how can i write this query?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be:

```
SELECT *, IF(INSTR(GROUP_CONCAT('--', nationality, '--'), '--US--'),
             'US', nationality)
FROM table GROUP BY age;
```

What this does is that GROUP_CONCAT combines all the nationalities of one age and if it finds the string 'US' among them, it returns 'US' and otherwise it returns the nationality as it would normally do. It also adds '--' in the beginning and end of a nationality to make 'US' become '--US--'. If you didn't do that, the query would also think that any other nationality which contains the consecutive characters 'US' would mean US. But those '--' characters are only used internally and are not shown in the final result.

---

Edit: Another (cleaner but longer) way came into my mind:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE nation='US'
               UNION
               SELECT * FROM table WHERE nation!='US') AS tmp
GROUP BY age;
```

So, first select persons whose nationality is US, then select persons whose nationality is not US and combine those two sets of persons so you get a table of persons in an order where there are first persons who are from US and then others. Then perform the GROUP BY operation to that table and you'll always get the nationality to be US if there's at least one person from US in that age, because it will always come first.

Comment: and add a where clause for US?

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your question at first, but now I did. so i edited my answer